# What clause is the sentence in the following paragraph?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, subordinate-clauses, cleft-constructions, attributives

> We all have ways of showing our sweetie how much we love them. But
>   celebrity relationship expert, Kailen Rosenberg, shares why it’s so
>   important and has tips, that’ll really show them how much, like
>   leaving love post-it-notes everywhere: “It’s the cutest, unique, warm
>   feeling that comes across upon these people/ when out of the blue,
>   especially after a bad fight, that all of a sudden, ***it’s this
>   refreshing reminder that /you are loved no matter what.*** It’s all
>   about awareness /and showing our partner /that they are absolutely
>   magical and amazing to us /no matter how many fights we’ve had and no
>   matter how tough times, you know, life and times can be, that they
>   still know they are really seen and they’re loved and acknowledged.”

As for the bold sentence in the paragraph, I think it is an emphatic sentence structure rather than an attributive clause since I could make a complete sentence after deleting "it's" and "that". So how can I explain this?

PS. Could the clause 'that you are loved no matter what.' an appositive clause?

Answer (score 0):

"That" can be omitted from introducing an attributive clause without affecting meaning or syntactical analysis. In this case, the clause is needed to specify what the reminder pertains to.

If you eliminate "it is" from the main clause "this refreshing reminder" is paired with no verb at all and thus is meaningless.

It is no wonder that you have trouble following this prose. It is written at the intellectual level of a dim adolescent in only nominally literate English with obvious typographical errors. My daughter was fourteen once, and the only thing adults can do at that age is be kind, loving, and firm. There is not point looking for sustained coherent thought even when the girl is very bright. (My son was fourteen once. You seldom are bothered by their utterances because they retreat into sullen silence around adults.)

Comment: can this clause 'that you are loved no matter what' be an appositive clause

Comment: @HenryWang Sure. It is modifying or restricting "reminder." There is nothibg complex about this part of the sentence. "It (the note) is a reminder." Utterly straightforward. A reminder of what? The fact that "you are loved." I am confused. Why do you need complex syntactical analysis to parse the gushings of a permanent adolescent. The whole thing simply means that a note saying "I love you" reminds you that someone truly loves you. The thought is so pathetically juvenile as almost to defy adult comprehension. Syntax won't help you, but remembering what you were like at 14 may.

Comment: This is not what I write. It comes from a native speaker who is a celebrity relationship expert, Kailen Rosenberg.

Comment: @JeffMorrow I dunno, my wife likes it when I give her notes like that. I don't think that's juvenile or pathetic. I will also tell you that three months after my aged father suffered a severe cervical spinal cord injury in a fall, he spent an entire day pecking out his yearly valentine card to my mother with hands that were unable to pick up a phone. It was my mother's last valentine card, because he never made it out of rehab and died nine months later. I don't think that's either pathetic or juvenile, which doesn't mean that I find your take offensive. Perhaps judgmental, though.

Comment: @BobRodes I admit to being judgmental. Where would any of us be if we had no judgment? And probably what got my judgment motor running here is not the notion of expressing affection but rather the very idea of a "celebrity relationship expert." How is one certified in that field? What was her dissertation on? Based on how this one writes, could anyone have actually read her entire dissertation. I like your answer: we have a good cop bad cop thing going here.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Your honesty is commendable. Where would any of us be if we had no judgment? In a whole lot happier place; judgment is the source of all the world's misery. The good news is that we don't really have any, because all of our judgments are subjective; there isn't "objectively correct" or "right" judgment. So we can always quit and let peace and tranquility take its place. To your other questions, my answer is that I don't care, although that is not to say that you shouldn't. That would be judgmental, after all. :)

Answer (score 0):

This paragraph is very poorly written. If I were the writer's editor, I would reject it and tell the writer to fix the run-on sentences and incorrect punctuation.

Furthermore, the speaker in the direct quote rambles from thought to thought without much consideration of whether what she's saying is grammatically correct.

I would analyze this as the speaker saying one thing, stopping before finishing the thought, backtracking, saying something else, stopping again before finishing the thought, backtracking again, and finally coming up with the complete sentence that you have bolded. I wouldn't attempt to analyze it in terms of clauses.

One gets the feeing that she felt she had to say something before fully composing her statement, because her second sentence is more coherent.